# How to do pipelining with RedisJSON (node's iorejson)?

Tags: redis, pipelining, redisjson

I have been working with RedisJSON for a few days and I couldn't find any information on how to use pipelining with node's 'iorejson' package.

Can somebody point me in the direction if used?

Answer (score 3):

It looks `iorejson` is not maintained, I would suggest you move to `node-redis` or `ioredis`

with `node-redis`:

```js
// npm install redis

import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();
client.on('error', err => console.error('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();

const replies = await client.multi()
  .json.set('key', { field: 'value' })
  .json.get('key', '$')
  .exec();
```

with `ioredis`:

```js
// npm install ioredis

import Redis from 'ioredis';

const client = new Redis();
client.on('error', err => console.error('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();

const replies = await client.multi()
  .call('JSON.SET', 'key', JSON.stringify({ field: 'value' }))
  .call('JSON.GET', 'key', '$')
  .exec();
```

Comment: Hi @Leibale, I used pipelining with 'ioredis' but in that case we have to always stringify the data being stored. So I'm trying to store JSON as is using RedisJSON module which doesn't need strigified versions. 'iorejson' is the package which sets json to the Redis.
But the problem is I can't create pipeline with this like in I did in 'ioredis'.

Comment: Then try node-redis, which calls `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` for you

Comment: The main reason I'm trying to store JSON as is to avoid stringifying and parsing the data back as I'm working with large data sets. Parsing takes more time than Redis giving the response.

Comment: You have to stringify and parse even with RedisJSON

Comment: No, I'm not doing that with RedisJSON.

Comment: this is the way RedisJSON works, it expects a JSON and returns a JSON (JSON stands for "javascript **string** object notation"). The advantage of using RedisJSON over plain "SET" with JSON in the value is that it'll understand the structure of the JSON and let you do stuff on parts of it (for example "JSON.GET key $.field" will only return "field" from the JSON stored in "key"

Comment: Yes exactly. No need of converting to string and parsing it back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249935/discussion-between-leibale-eidelman-and-gowthamss).